# Sorting contents of a folder by date created in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I have a code which renames the files to 1, 2, 3... in a folder. What I want is to first sort the contents according to date created and then rename the files. Because now its all messed up. I need it for video editing. Thanks in advance!

```
import os

path = os.chdir("C:\\Users\\manis\\Desktop\\Vlog")

i=1
for file in os.listdir(path):

  new_file_name = "{}.mp4".format(i)
  os.rename(file, new_file_name)

  i = i + 1
```

Comment: `os.chdir()` does not return a value, so it's implicitly None. And you probably shouldn't be using it anyway. Just use fully-qualified path/filenames where needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the files depending on their date created

```
path = "./directory"
files_sorted_by_date = []

filepaths = [os.path.join(path, file) for file in os.listdir(path)]
file_statuses = [(os.stat(filepath), filepath) for filepath in filepaths]
files = ((status[stat.ST_CTIME], filepath) for status, filepath in file_statuses if stat.S_ISREG(status[stat.ST_MODE]))
for creation_time, filepath in sorted(files):
    creation_date = time.ctime(creation_time)
    filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
    files_sorted_by_date.append(creation_date + " " + filename)
print(files_sorted_by_date)
```

> OUTPUT
>
> ['Fri Mar 27 18:56:56 2020 sample1.txt',
>
> 'Fri Mar 27 18:56:56 2020 sample2.txt',
>
> 'Fri Mar 27 18:56:56 2020 sample3.txt']

source: `https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-files-in-a-directory-sorted-by-creation-date-in-python`

Comment: Edited the code and source, this should do it